# Can I create own google chrome installer?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to know, that is it possible create own google chrome installer ? With own extensions a search engine. Like in mozilla.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why this was voted down – a legitimate question imho. Could be very handy for organizations and/or controlled deployment across big infrastructures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own installer using [Google Omaha](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/), the free downloader/installer used for Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The **[Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/)** project is an open-source browser project based on WebKit and behind Chrome.
I didn't verify Chrome license but I doubt that anybody has the right to modify this program or set another search engine than Google, though a bundle of extensions is something different and could be possible.

Comment: I know, but for mozilla was created special program, where you choose your extension and just create installer, it is very simple